# What is the best dimension for android app?

Tags: android, android-layout, screen-resolution, dpi, dimension

i know you must implement lots of different layout for different sizes and dpi screens but i want to ignore some performance issues and work on just one dimension for beginning. I have chosen drawable-xhdpi with 640x960(or 720x1280 i'm not sure about which one is better) dimensions(this is just for android mobile phones not tablets), is this the right way to make my appo perate on the most of the mobile phones such as galaxy s5, nexus etc? Thanks.

Comment: You better choose drawable-xxhdpi or even drawable-xxxhdpi :) And yes usually AOS takes care about lowering the dimension (resolution) of drawables. Lets say you have drawable-xhdpi only resources and you are running app on hdpi device. So AOS will lower resolution of anyl image from drawable-xhdpi it needs and then use it.

Comment: If you want to target specific devices - get familiar with their screen dimensions and screen density values and proceed accordingly; if you want to target a large array of devices - you'll have to provide resources for multiple resolutions

Comment: i want to choose two dimension for phones and tablets :) so what dimension  do i have to go with for xxhdpi?

Answer (score 2):

If you are just a beginner trying to get your feet in the water, just use the dimensions for a phone that you have access to.
If you are trying to do more advanced work, the more proper way to do it is not to develop for a specific dimension, but to have a responsive design that rescales or rearranges at runtime based on the dimensions of the device that is detected.

One way to get the runtime dimensions are to use:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
```

Also see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Definitely develop for a device which you have access to

Comment: for a responsive design, do not i have to do layout for xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi etc. what am i going to do with width and height?

Comment: I added a link for http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html  ; I think you are refering to the section under "Designing alternative layouts and drawables".  But regardless of the process for responsive design, if you are just starting, just do your first layout for a device that you have access to.